# Realistic Mythical Creatures

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, genetic-engineering, mythology

What mythological creatures could be realistically created? In my world, there are people capable of advanced genetic creation and manipulation. I was just wondering what creatures would be plausible that they could create. For example, a phoenix is a lot less plausible than creating a Griffin or centaur.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Chidi. I suspect this question may well be closed as primarily opinion based in its current form but as a general rule, I'd look at this in terms of what extra-natural powers a creature may have and use that as an indicator of plausibility. For instance, a fire breathing dragon will be hard because animals that size and weight break the square cube law for strength and flight, and also we have no natural analog for breathing fire in the real world. Closest to natural animals, easiest to create in a lab.

Comment: This is far too broad in scope to be feasibly answerable, and is likely to get closed for that reason. A question about the realism of a _specific_ mythical creature would be on-topic, for which I'd recommend you look at the [Anatomically Correct](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/anatomically-correct-series) series of questions. See if any of those answer what you're looking for, or distinguish your particular version of a mythical creature from those in other questions on this site and ask a new question about that specific creature.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I appreciate the comment. I'll take note of what you said. And thanks for pointing out how opinionated and broad it is guys. If I make a new question, I'll be sure to revise it. Thanks for the suggestion Palarran!

Answer (score 5):

None of the ones you mentioned are feasible I would think. Chopping creatures in half and reassembling them as hybrids will not work. Nor would things like defying physics by having 30 foot dragons, or breathing fire for that matter.

Multiheaded snakes are a possibility, giant creatures (including humans) and things like that would be possible. Cyclops, unicorns and suchlike that are more modifications of a form rather than have magical or unrealistic powers.

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you're saying. Thanks for your answer, it definitely gave things to think about and creatures to cross off my list.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe focus on the mythical creatures that are actually more based on reality. A lot of creatures were actually inspired by other real animals. The unicorn for example was likely inspired by an extinct Siberian wholly rhinoceros called an Elasmotherium. In fact, many existing creatures were once thought to be entirely mythical such as the gorilla, squid, narwhal, komodo dragon, and platypus.

Basically drop anything half human, humanoid, or chimera-esk and then drop any magical powers that can't be explained scientifically (like maybe breathing fire was actually spitting acidic venom, still leaves burn like scarring and feels like burning). In the end its still just up to you, but I would say try and come up with your handwavium for a bunch of creatures you like and then choose the most believable ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's not something I considered so I'll look into it! It definitely helped me narrow down some ideas.